# Accessing MS Access hosted in Ubuntu server from Java in a windows based VPS?

Tags: java, windows, ms-access, ubuntu-server

Hi I have this little big problem I have a legacy VB6 desktop application that connects to a MS Access database hosted in a local Ubuntu server machine that is being shared to the LAN as a SMB share and I have a Tomcat web application hosted in a Windows based VPS, these are

### Requirements

- Read information from the MS Access db and show it in the webapp (On URL visit and almost real-time accuracy).
- Update the MS Access db with information received through the website.

### Facts

- 20Mb < db size
- Shared with 15 ~ 25 users.
- Constant local update and querying.

The file size is small because It is being truncated as it grows tool large( > 100Mb)
Now I know that the arquitecture isn't the best and that MS Access is at its limits, a migration to full Java and MySQL is on the way, but it's going to take a long time....in the meantime I need a way to implement that feature, here are my options.

---

### Option 1

Access the db in ubuntu server through a VPN directly from the webapp.

Cons

- Is it possible?.
- Slow connection.
- May lock the db MORE frequently as it happens quite often locally.

### Option 2

Have a local webapp run in Ubuntu server that exposes the db as a REST API, so updates would be handled by the local webapp.

Cons:

- Hard to use MS Access in a UNIX environment, looking at [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) and [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/), but so far I haven't been able to use it.
- Well, writing the whole app and securing the server.

### Option 3

Any suggestions?

Thank you if you read this far, any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it would be as quick to move the data to a MySQL back-end and continue with the Access front-end until you are ready for your final upgrade.

Comment: I tend to agree. I would move the data to some type of SQL server. It just not clear if they can modify the VB6 application or they have source code.

Comment: Unfortunately you will not be remotely accessing that MSAccess file from a *nix box unless you can get IIS installed with the proper ADO libraries...  Your best option will be to get that data into a new db platform and update the code or get the db file onto a new system that is running IIS with the proper ado libraries.  

also you say you have not been able to use unixODBC or FreeTDS, are you encountering errors getting it going?  if so post them :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I missed something in your description, I think you might be confusing the differences between an API and a library. Basically, ODBC is an API which is implemented as a library and commonly used on Windows based machines through additional data access libraries like ADO and ADO.NET. I mention this since you referred to unixODBC as a solution. It would not be a complete solution as there is more to it than just the API alone.

In simple terms, the database file you created with Microsoft Access is a .MDB flat file database (ok, there is a little bit more to it, but in terms of treating it as a database, that is all that matters here). If you know how the structure of the .MDB file works, you could write your own library that reads/writes to it. Of course, this is not trivial and on the Windows platforms, this is provided for you by Microsoft using the libraries included in the OS. This is also referred to as a JET driver and database. JET is the database format that the .MDB file implements and is used by Access and other applications via the correspondingly named JET drivers.

So to find an equivalent option for non-Windows platforms, you need some sort of library that knows how to natively read/write to the .MDB file directly. If you are trying to use the .MDB file at the same time from an Access application, then you need to make sure the library you choose supports simultaneous mutli-user access to the database.

In a quick search, there do appear to be some solutions that I could find. The first one appears that it might have some functional limitations. The second appears to be a commercial product.

[MDB Tools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/)

[Easysoft JET/Access Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html)

Comment: You should rethink about suggesting MDB Tools, it's documented as [read-only](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/faq.html#what).